# How can I change a Google Sheet Tab Index of Sheet that is not Active?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to change the index (tab) order of a google tab in another spreadsheet from the active spreadsheet. When I run the log, using openById, I can see the other spreadsheet and the tab with correct index, which is 13:

```
Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.openById('123456789').getSheetByName('sheet_name').getIndex());

Output: 10:00:39 AM Info    13.0
```

How can I move the index from 13 to 1? I tried using the .moveTo(n) function, like this:

```
SpreadsheetApp.openById('123456789').getSheetByName('sheet_name').moveTo(1);
```

But it throws this error:

```
10:04:33 AM Error TypeError: SpreadsheetApp.openById(...).getSheetByName(...).moveTo is not a function update_SLA_SS    @ Code.gs:106
```

Anyone know how I can change the tab index?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-I used google sheet record macro and I get this code:

-Seems there is only function moveActiveSheet(), moveTo() not exist

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheet2'), true);
  spreadsheet.moveActiveSheet(1);
```

Comment: Thanks. I found moveTo(n) on the developer's site, but, indeed, it doesn't work .. and moveActiveSheet() does.